# How can I restart my application in .NET 5?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, backgroundworker, .net-5

I have a background worker that checks state of some variable and if this variable the same as was 5 minutes ago, it means that application is frozen and should be restarted, that's is the way how I implemented this logic, but this don't restart app it just throw an exception:

```
 public void ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
 {
        Task.Run(async () =>
        {
          while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
          {
              await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_delayBetweenChecksInSeconds));
              double exTotal = metricExTotal;   

              if (exTotal == _previousexTotal)
              {
                      Environment.Exit(-1);
              }
              _previousexTotal = exTotal;
          }
      })
      .ContinueWith(task =>
      {
          Environment.Exit(-1);
      }, TaskContinuationOptions.OnlyOnFaulted)
         .ConfigureAwait(false);
}
```

How it could be correctly implemented, so it will restart app?

Comment: Create or edit a file in the `bin` folder.

Comment: NEVER tell us that an exception is thrown without specifying exactly where and the details of the exception.

Comment: If your app has crashed or is stuck in a loop, it might not be able to restart itself. The correct approach is to have a separate launcher app which runs the actual application. Then the launcher app checks the shared state (perhaps via a named [`EventWaitHandle`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.eventwaithandle?view=net-6.0)). The launcher can then terminate the app process and restart it, if it needs to.

Comment: A separate launcher is useful for a lot of other things too, such as handling preconditions that  the app itself shouldn't need to know about. You can also more easily install updates for the app when using a separate launcher. But you have to keep the launcher as simple as possible, and make sure that you're careful to handle exceptions - you don't want the launcher crashing.